# Periodic data ingestion from mongodb to csv

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a data producer source (mongodb) from where we are consuming data. We need to periodically move data (15 min periodically)from different mongodb collections to different csvs through a lambda function. Of late, the application has grown much and we are having missing data & memory issues with the current architecture.

Is there an alternate architecture we can implement to replace the current lambda based architecture ? Any open source frameworks that might be more effective ?

Comment: What memory issues? Do you mean to say your Lamda functions are timing out or going OOM?

Comment: Sometimes the files are so big that it crashes due to OOM. I was looking at some of the alternatives I can have.

Comment: What is the average file size and how much growth do you further see in future? Have you tried reducing the period from 15 min to something smaller to begin with (If that is something that you can do!)

Comment: This will keep on growing. Yes, we have tried changing the period interval to 5 min too, we still had failures (but lesser ). However, here I am more interested to see what other open source frameworks I can use ..

Comment: You essentially are looking at a job scheduler that does a long running job (reading from multiple sources and creating a .csv). Do you really need a framework for this?